# Analog to Digital input scaling equation works in codeblocks but not on Microcontroller

Tags: math, numbers, scaling, microchip

I'm so lost on how to fix this, it should be so simple. I'm using a pic16F1526 and trying to scale the analog to digital reading from 0-255 to 50-100 roughly. I am using this equation

result = ((user_input + 200) * 200) / 800;

In code blocks and on my calculator it works at all numbers from 0-255 and it works perfectly whether I use 8 bit, 16 bit variables in code bloacks. 
I've already verified that the AtoD input is working correctly sending the data to the UART. Even if I enter static numbers in place of the sample I get weird results.

When the acd reads a 255 or I enter a 255 the equation gives me a 31 in decimal instead of 100 like it's supposed to. The only thing I can think of is something is getting messed up in the way an 8 bit PIC does it's math since it's an a bit micro.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are getting the correct results on in codeblack because of integer promotion and getting the incorrect results in the hardware because of variable overflow.

- uint8_t Can contain 0 to 255
- int8_t Can contain -126 125
- uint16_t Can contain 0 to 65635
- ...

Assuming you have uint16_t, the micro's math will go as follows:

- `((255 + 200) * 200) / 800`
- `(455 * 200) / 800` : `455 * 200` **Overflows the 16 bit variable!**
- `( 25464 ) / 800`: Note that `91000 & 0xFFFF == 25464`
- `31`

You can work around this issue by simplifying your equation :
 `(user_input + 200) / 4` is equivalent to `((user_input + 200) * 200) / 800` and will not overflow at 16 bits although your accuracy is not very high as ImaginaryHuman072889 pointed out.

Comment: ohhh nice! I suspected something like this going on but had no idea how to work it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to linearly map the numbers 0-255 to the numbers 50-100.

Back to good old `y = mx + b` algebra.

When `x = 0`, `y = 50`. Therefore:

```
y = mx + b
50 = m*0 + b
b = 50
```

When `x = 255`, `y = 100`. Therefore:

```
y = mx + 50
100 = m*255 +50
m*255 = 50
m = 50/255 = 10/51
```

Therefore, the precise answer is:

```
y = (10/51)*x + 50
```

---

On a side note, I have no idea how you got the result of `31` when plugging in `100` into your formula. See below.

```
(255+200)*200/800 = 113.75
```

Comment: Good point, I didn't even bother reducing it down to a simpler equation i was sort of rushing and just plugging numbers into my calculator because I was modifying a different equation, well that and math isn't my strong point.